# Prove there eixsts $u\in A, v\in B$ s.t. $\inf\{\|a-b\| \mid a\in A, b\in B\}=\|u-v\|$, for compact $A$ and closed $B$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, supremum-and-infimum

I want to prove that for nonemptyset $A, B\subset \mathbb R^n$, if $A$ is compact and $B$ is closed, then there exists $u\in A,v\in B$ s.t. $\inf\{\|a-b\| \mid a\in A, b\in B\}=\|u-v\|$.
(i.e., the minumum of $\{\|a-b\| \mid a\in A, b\in B\}$ is exists.)

The outline is given:

> we may assume $B$ is compact by embedding $A$ inside a big enough ball that interacts $B$. Then, $A\times B$ is compact so the function $(a,b)\mapsto \|a-b\|$ maps onto a compact set and reaches its bounds.

I want to complete the proof.

---

Since $B$ is not empty, there exists $b_0\in B.$

And since $A$ is bounded, there exists $r>0$ s.t. $A\subset \overline{B_r(b_0)}$.

Let $B':=B\cap \overline{B_r(b_0)}.$ This is bounded and closed  thus compact.

Then, $A\times B'$ is compact.

The mapping $f:A\times B' \to \mathbb R$ given by $(a,b)\mapsto \|a-b\|$ is continuous so $f(A\times B')$ is compact.

Now, $f(A\times B')=\{\|a-b\| \mid a\in A, b\in B'\}$

---

I cannot proceed from here. I don't understand the expression "the function $(a,b)\mapsto \|a-b\|$ maps onto a compact set and reaches its bounds" in the outline.

How should I do to complete the proof ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Since $A\times B'$ is compact and $f$ is continuous, then $f(A\times B')$ is compact hence closed. Therefore, $f(A\times B')$ always has a minimum.

Comment: But, that is the minimum value of $f(A\times B')=\{\|a-b\|\mid a\in A, b\in B'\}$. Is it also the minimum value of $\{\|a-b\|\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$ ? @Marlovo

Comment: Indeed the minimum values of the two sets may not be the same. How about using $B'=B\cap\overline{\bigcup_{a\in A}B_r(a)}$ for $r$ large?

Comment: I can see $\min f(A\times B')\geqq \min f(A\times B)$ since $B'\subset B$, but I cannot see the opposite inequality. Could you explain ? @Marlovo

Comment: Since we are minimizing $\|a-b\|$ for $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, then it suffices to restrict our search to those $b\in B$ that are close to $A$.